# Unable to update existing app store app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

We have transferred our app from one account to another as owners got changed. Also the certificate has expired. Whenever I am trying to update the app store app by next version via Xcode it is always giving me this error:

[image]

What should I do in this case? I don't have any access to previous developer machine.

Comment: it seems that your old and new app's bundle id is not same. pls check bundle id of old and new app.

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal Both are same.